# headers and cpp files

Tags: c++, file, header

I got this super simple code I'm trying to compile under Linux (first time working under linux)
I programmed with c++ before and I understand the concept of headers and cpp files...

Sentence.h

```
#ifndef SENTENCE_H_
#define SENTENCE_H_

std::vector<std::string> split(char sentence[]);
void printWords(std::vector<std::string> words);

#endif
```

Sentence.cpp

```
#include "../include/Sentence.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> split(char sentence[]) {
    string str(sentence);
    string buf; // Have a buffer string
    stringstream ss(str); // Insert the string into a stream

    vector<string> tokens; // Create vector to hold our words

    while (ss >> buf)
        tokens.push_back(buf);

    return tokens;
}

void printWords(std::vector<std::string> words) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
           std::cout << words[i] << endl;
}
```

And I'm getting those few errors which I can't figure out why...

```
daniel@daniel-ubuntu-server:~/workspace/HW1$ make
g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -c -Linclude -o bin/Sentence.o src/Sentence.cpp
In file included from src/Sentence.cpp:1:0:
src/../include/Sentence.h:4:6: error: ‘vector’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
 std::vector<std::string> split(char sentence[]);
      ^
src/../include/Sentence.h:5:22: error: variable or field ‘printWords’ declared void
 void printWords(std::vector<std::string> words);
                      ^
src/../include/Sentence.h:5:17: error: ‘vector’ is not a member of ‘std’
 void printWords(std::vector<std::string> words);
                 ^
src/../include/Sentence.h:5:29: error: ‘string’ is not a member of ‘std’
 void printWords(std::vector<std::string> words);
                             ^
src/../include/Sentence.h:5:42: error: ‘words’ was not declared in this scope
 void printWords(std::vector<std::string> words);
                                          ^
makefile:10: recipe for target 'bin/Sentence.o' failed
make: *** [bin/Sentence.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Think about the order of your `#include` directives.

Comment: Does `printWords` need to copy the vector just to output it?

Answer (score 4):

Your header uses the std::vector class, but the vector class code is never included in it. Add `#include <vector>` to the header file so the class will be loaded before the rest of `Sentence.h`.

This will also help in other files that might use `Sentece.h`, since they won't have to include the vector class by themselves.

Answer (score 2):

`Sentence.h` uses `std::vector` but does not include `<vector>` header. Same situation with `std::string`.